# Создание файла в конкретной директории на сайте

Tags: php

Необходимо создать файл в определённой директории на сайте. Для этого пишу код:

```
$text = "Text";
$fp = fopen(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH.'my-table.php', "w");
fwrite($fp, $text);
fclose($fp);
```

`SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH` - константа, содержит путь до шаблона сайта
Подскажите, что я делаю не правильно, если я убираю константу, то файл создаётся в папке со скриптом, а если я оставляю её, то ничего не создаётся?

Comment: очевидно в константе проблема и в её значении

Comment: Покажите, что выводит `var_dump(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH.'my-table.php');`

Comment: если я пишу echo `SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH`, то выводит /os/templates/site-templates
Отсюда делаем вывод, что константа содержит путь до шаблона
`var_dump(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH.'my-table.php');` если так написать, то /os/templates/site-templatesmy-table.php

Слеш добавил, но файл не создался

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если `SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH` определен, то может быть разделители указаны не верно.
И как минимум нет разделителя между SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH и названием файла.

```
if (!defined('SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH')) {
    die('SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH не определен!');
}
if(!is_writable(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH)){
    die('Нет доступа!');
}
$path = SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH;
str_replace('/',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,$path);
$text = "Text";
$fp = fopen($path.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'my-table.php', "w");
fwrite($fp, $text);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: спасибо, не хватало прав для записи